# Custom snackbar has a text overlay

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I am making a custom snackbar with the following

```
fun showSnack(view: View, text:String){
 
    val snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, text, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
    val snackbarView = snackbar.view
     snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(view.context)
    val layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_snack,null,false)
    layout.custom_text.text = text
    val slayout = snackbar.view as SnackbarLayout
    slayout.addView(layout,0)
    snackbar.show()
}
```

custom_snack.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/off_white"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light"
    app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    >

<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/appCompatImageView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/home" />

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/toast_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="sample text"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlSymmetry" />
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>



</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

using it like so:

```
showSnack(findViewById(android.R.id.content),"Access Granted")
```

the custom snackbar showsup in the screen but there is a text overlay and I can't figure where it's coming from. Extra text Extra text Extra text Extra text Extra text Extra text Extra text Extra text

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
val snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, text, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
```

Use:

```
val snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
```

Comment: Hello @Gabriele Mariotti can you please take a look at this my IDE font is unreable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63128504/as-ide-font-unreable