# AS IDE font unreable

Tags: android-studio, intellij-14

I changed my windows system font to Google Sans which I like very much but now android studio ide font is not being displayed properly. How do I fix it, I do want to keep my system font though.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

After some digging I found a file in

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\.AndroidStudio4.0\config\options
```

called ui.Inf.xml

which was

```
<application>
  <component name="UISettings">
    <option name="SHOW_MAIN_TOOLBAR" value="true" />
    <option name="SHOW_MEMORY_INDICATOR" value="true" />
    <option name="SHOW_NAVIGATION_BAR" value="false" />
    <option name="SHOW_STATUS_BAR" value="false" />
  </component>
</application>
I added these 3 lines


 <option name="FONT_FACE" value="Consolas" />
    <option name="FONT_SIZE" value="24" />
    <option name="OVERRIDE_NONIDEA_LAF_FONTS" value="true" />
```

saved the file and restarted as.
Done!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!